# Execution failed for task ':react-native-zoom-us:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native

Please anyone have the solution? then please share . When I used the.

`react-native-zoom-us": "^5.0.0`

the the Sdk was intialized but on Join meeting it was not working and App crashes So I tried to use the Latest version now its not working.

Currently Using

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.0",
"react-native-zoom-us": "^6.16.4",

  android/build.gradle
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    targetSdkVersion = 31
```

I followed these steps.
Install npm lib Run npm install react-native-zoom-us

[Android only] Get Meeting SDK with *.aar files

The following manual steps are needed because ZoomUs SDK does not expose *.aar files directly.

Register on ZoomUs (https://zoom.us/signup#/signup)
Go to https://marketplace.zoom.us/develop/create
Click on Create placed on Meeting SDK card, choose App Name and click on Continue
Fill in Company Name, Name and Email address and click on Continue

On Download step choose Android then v5.13.1.11014 and click on download icon
Uzip the content of downloaded zoom-sdk-android-5.13.1.11014.zip

Copy two *.aar files to the node_modules/react-native-zoom-us folder of your project:
cp ~/Downloads/zoom-sdk-android-5.13.1.11014/mobilertc-android-studio/commonlib/commonlib.aar node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/commonlib

cp ~/Downloads/zoom-sdk-android-5.13.1.11014/mobilertc-android-studio/mobilertc/mobilertc.aar node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/mobilertc

[This is the link same Question on  Github](https://github.com/mieszko4/react-native-zoom-us/issues/260)
Errors

```
Task :react-native-zoom-us:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
176 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 169 up-to-date
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsActivity.java:4: warning: [deprecation] MeetingActivity in us.zoom.sdk has been deprecated
import us.zoom.sdk.MeetingActivity;
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsModule.java:76: error: RNZoomUsModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onLocalRecordingPrivilegeRequested(IRequestLocalRecordingPrivilegeHandler) in InMeetingServiceListener
public class RNZoomUsModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ZoomSDKInitializeListener, InMeetingServiceListener, MeetingServiceListener, InMeetingShareController.InMeetingShareListener, LifecycleEventListener {
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsModule.java:1122: warning: [deprecation] onShareActiveUser(long) in InMeetingShareListener has been deprecated
public void onShareActiveUser(long userId) {
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsModule.java:209: warning: [deprecation] Integer(int) in Integer has been deprecated
videoViews.add(new Integer(tagId));
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsModule.java:219: warning: [deprecation] Integer(int) in Integer has been deprecated
videoViews.remove(new Integer(tagId));
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsVideoView.java:61: warning: [deprecation] Long(long) in Long has been deprecated
users.remove(new Long(inMeetingService.getMyUserID()));
^
/Volumes/ReporteqProjects/MobileApp/node_modules/react-native-zoom-us/android/src/main/java/ch/milosz/reactnative/RNZoomUsActivity.java:6: warning: [deprecation] MeetingActivity in us.zoom.sdk has been deprecated
public class RNZoomUsActivity extends MeetingActivity {
^
1 error
6 warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-zoom-us:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:/Users/shafqatbari/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e9b9775f38bad343aa040e35c99099c7/transformed/jetified-mobilertc/res/layout/activity_media_player.xml:7: AAPT: error: attribute controller_layout_id (aka com.salushealth:controller_layout_id) not found.`[![Pic of Error][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the newest version 6.16.5. Now its working.
When I reported the issue they responded to that and updated to new version and shared the details with me Thanks to
"react-native-zoom-us" team

This is the answer
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/mieszko4/react-native-zoom-us/issues/260#issuecomment-1429206649)